# Poner la posición de la primera y última aparición de un número en una lista c++

Tags: c++, bucles, codeblocks

Buenas soy algo nuevo en programación y me han enviado una tarea en la que me dicen que debo introducir una cantidad indefinida de números acabada en 0(ya que me han dicho que no use arrays) y que detecte cada vez que aparece un 12 y que me diga la posición en la que lo hace.

Yo tengo este código escrito:

```
using namespace std;

int main () {

    int secuencia , n;

    cout << "Introduzca la secuencia de numeros: ";
    cin >> secuencia;
    n=1;

   while (secuencia != 0) {

    cin >> secuencia;
    n=n+1;

    if (secuencia==12) {
        cout << "La primera aparicion del 12 es en: " << n << endl;
        cout << "La ultima aparicion del 12 es en: " << n << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Si alguien me puede decir como completarlo lo agradecería porque el resultado me sale:

> ```
> Introduzca la secuencia de numeros: 1 12 3 12 0
> La primera aparicion del 12 es en: 2
> La ultima aparicion del 12 es en: 2
> La primera aparicion del 12 es en: 4
> La ultima aparicion del 12 es en: 4
>
> Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 3.785 s
> Press any key to continue.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Tu error es que has puesto al final un if sin sentido, si eliminas ese if ya estaría.
Código final correcto, testeado:

```
int main() 
{

    int secuencia , n;

    cout << "Introduzca la secuencia de numeros: ";
    cin >> secuencia;
    n=1;
    while (secuencia != 0) 
    {

        cin >> secuencia;
        n=n+1;

        if (secuencia==12) 
        {
                cout << "La primera aparicion del 12 es en: " << n << endl;
        }

    } // END OF WHILE
    
    return 0;
}
```

Fue testeado correctamente en MingW g++

Comment: perdon ese no era el codigo correcto el último if no debería estar pero me pide la primera vez que aparece el 12 y la última es decir que si yo pongo 1 12 3 12 4 12 0 me diga que la primera vez que aparece es en el puesto 2 y la última en el 6 creo que ya está corregido

Comment: @FranciscoManuel02 la primera y la última vez que aparece 12 **no lo pides en el enunciado que compartes** debemos deducirlo de la salida que muestras.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo, debes introducir números hasta introducir un cero, y cada vez que se introduzca un 12 decir en qué posición se introdujo.

Tan sólo necesitas un índice (para saber en qué posición de la secuencia estás):

```
for (int indice = 0, numero = 1; numero; ++indice)
{
    cout << "Introduce numero: ";
    cin >> numero;

    if (numero == 12)
        cout << numero << " aparece en la posicion " << (indice + 1) << '\n';
}
```

Si además necesitas saber la primera y última aparición de `12` (como se deduce de tu salida, pero no de tu enunciado), necesitarás guardar dichos índices:

```
int primero = numeric_limits<int>::max();
int ultimo = numeric_limits<int>::min();

for (int indice = 1, numero = numeric_limits<int>::max(); numero; ++indice)
{
    cout << "Introduce numero: ";
    cin >> numero;

    if (numero == 12)
    {
        primero = std::min(primero, indice);
        ultimo = std::max(ultimo, indice);
        cout << numero << " aparece en la posicion " << indice << '\n';
    }
}

cout << "Primera aparicion en " << primero << "\nUltima aparicion en " << ultimo;
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZBPa4NAEMXPO59iSA8xJAW1/6Px3lsvvQXKopswoKOsKxRKPrudzWrTQktBZJl5895vpuy667LWfBzHK@KyHiqDObW9s0Y3BVxqNTXk@gKA2GGjiaMVfIAaeuIjsm5M3@nSYO@qDEB5UWepMbbFHfIgDyrfgkcuzWK7bfR7tMqCdKgdNX8rfZh3PbQWI68nrkjCdphswsg/KZMow/U6jK5ACbwq28FhnuPimZ1tq0E8g3KLi8z3ibEo5mkhUHTAaE6U@FSMzk7qsq2cIDBPpc2E65dV6mvVIBO8UPmpmsGmKI@IutPWCKFhrDV2bU8ltSwN6U4Hkddyz0tvcQL54LLhyxlGn13CoJlmZ3Kv2vOrp/lNFjD9Eaxxg2WMMziNYwIp3MAt3ME9PMAjPEESQ5JAkn77x76cQgzwCQ)</kbd>.

---

**Explicación**

Todo número es implícitamente convertible a una expresión booleana, siendo `0` equivalente a `false` y cualquier otro valor equivalente a `true`, por ese motivo, el bucle `for` se interrumpe si el valor entrado es cero.

En el bucle `for`, puedes declarar tantas variables (del mismo tipo) como necesites, por eso `indice` y `numero` son declaradas en la primera parte del bucle `for`, estas variables vivirán sólo mientras viva el bucle, por eso `primero` y `ultimo` se declaran fuera, ya que se necesitan fuera del bucle.